# Creating a batch file to modify the filenames in a directory

Tags: csv, batch-file, for-loop, nested

Im trying to build a batch file.

I have 30 csv files in a folder

My intention is

1. Get each file name (Example is 097_021216_192332.csv)
2. Extract the first 3 digits
3. Compare it with a lookup table ( lookup1.bat) against which i have marked another string

> EG: lookup1.bat

```
@echo 107=B_05-
@echo 097=B_06-
@echo 149=B_07-
@echo 109=B_08-
@echo 101=B_09-
@echo 105=B_10-
@echo 098=B_11-
```

So here i will get "B_06-"

4. Modify the file name with this "B_06-" prefix and rename the file

Here is my code , i have only basic ideas about looping and im struggling a lot.Thanks for any help.

```
@echo on

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


for %%a in ("*.csv") do ( 
    set FileName=%%~na
    goto:stepa
    goto:eof

)
:stepa
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ("%FileName%") do ( 
    set A=%%a 
    echo %A%
    )

@SET MN=%A%
@FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i IN ('lookup1.bat') DO @IF %%i EQU %MN% SET MW=%%j

@ECHO The board number corresponding to %MN% is %MW%.

set "str=%MW%%FileName%"
echo "%str%"    

Ren "!FileName!" "!str!"

:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of problems with the structure of your program. If you want to call a *subroutine* from inside a `for` command the right way is using `call`, not `goto`, and the `goto :eof` command must be placed *after* the `for` ends. However, this code is simple enough so it don't requires a subroutine.

The table lookup method is more efficient (and also simpler, IMHO) if you use an *array* to load the table just once, and then directly access its elements via an *index*.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the lookup file with lookup1.bat file,
rem this program create lines like this one:
rem 097=B_06-
call lookup1.bat > lookup1.txt

rem Load the lookup table from the file,
rem this method create _array elements_ like this one:
rem set "table[097]=B_06-"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (lookup1.txt) do set "table[%%a]=%%b"

rem Process the files in current folder,
rem file name format is this:
rem ###_restOfFileName.csv
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /B *.csv') do (
   @ECHO The board number corresponding to %%a is !table[%%a]!.
   ren "%%a_%%b" "!table[%%a]!%%b"
)
```

You may test if the board number is not defined for a file via an additional `if not defined table[%%a] ...` command placed inside the `for`.

You may directly create the `lookup1.txt` file with your text editor; just eliminate all these `@echo` parts from `lookup1.bat` and change the extension.

You may review a detailed explanation on array use in Batch files at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).